# What does cupid do in linux?

Tags: linux, function, module, kernel

I've seen module names like cupid during installation, and am curious what it really does. I searched google but didn't find much clue.

I believe stackoverflow experts should know if cupid is a module/driver inside linux kernel or distribution?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe `cpuid`? If it is, see `cpuid(4)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cpuid is a tool that can be installed on linux as an rpm

Linux tool to dump x86 CPUID information about the CPU(s)